# Would this INSERT statement work? Errata in textbook?

Tags: sql-server, errors

I was taking a practice test for Microsoft Certification 70-461 and wanted to confirm if what I saw was an error (this is from the official Microsoft Press book, Ninth printing. I did not see this on existing errata).

> Question:
>
> You are adding tables to the `Hovercraft` database. You create
>   a table by using the following statement:
>
> ```
>   Create Table Hovercraft.Testing
>   ( TestIdentifier uniqueidentifier
>   DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID() PRIMARY KEY,
>   HullId tinyint NOT NULL,
>   TestDate date NOT NULL,
>   Registration nvarchar(8) NOT NULL,
>   Notes nvarchar(max)
>   )
> ```
>
> Which of the following statements can you use to insert data into this table? (Each correct answer presents a complete solution. Choose two.)

The choices are:

1. `INSERT INTO Hovercraft.Testing (Notes, HullID, TestDate, Registration,)
    VALUES (N'Hovercraft requires maintenance.', 142, '20120715', N'AAA320')`
2. `INSERT INTO Hovercraft.Testing (HullID, TestDate, Registration, Notes)
    VALUES (124, '20120722', N'AAA321', N'Hovercraft in good condition. Next service in six months' time')`
3. `INSERT INTO Hovercraft.Testing (HullID, TestDate, Registration, Notes)
    VALUES (247, '20120722', N'ABCD54321', N'Hovercraft in good condition. Next service in three months' time')`
4. `INSERT INTO Hovercraft.Testing (Notes, HullID, TestDate, Registration,)
    VALUES (N'Hovercraft requires maintenance.', 842, '20120709', N'AAB121')`

The answer key claims the first two are correct. However, shouldn't the additional apostrophe in the word "months" cause an error in the statement?

I apologize in advance if this isn't the right forum to confirm this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct, the second would fail due to the extra quote. This may be just a misprint caused by an over-aggressive grammar checker, or indeed it could be an apostrophe rather than a quote, and the font delineation is difficult to determine.

- The first one will succeed.
- The second one would fail due to the single quote (if it's a quote)
- The third one would fail due to registration being longer than 8 characters (and the quote, if it's a quote)
- The fourth one would fail as the `HullId` is out of range for a `tinyint`

Side note: why they would put a `Hovercraft schema` in the `Hovercraft` database is beyond me, and a great example of nonsensical design.